# I3-wm get monitors does not exist

Tags: xorg, i3

Can someone help me, I have been struggling for a while. I tried X -configure, then cp the be config, I tried a fresh install of i3 and I tried a fresh install of the whole os and keep hitting this error. If I remove my xinitrc it runs with xorg's default window manager, but as soon as I try to run i3 it crashes. Thanks

I can't upload an image for some reason so the whole error is

```
/usr/local/bin/i3: Undefined symbol "xcb_randr_get_monitors"
xinit: connection to X server lost
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. If I install via ports instead of pkg install it works